# render GridView item text

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid, render

Here is script of unsuccessful attempt to render grid item (cell).
Idea is to process input value and return it to cell - render.

ASP

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView_stations" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="mailreport" AllowSorting="True" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="id" >
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="70px" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" ItemStyle-CssClass="padding-left" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" >
                <HeaderStyle  CssClass="padding-left" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <ItemStyle CssClass="padding-left"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text='<%#renderthis(Eval("id"))%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' OnClick="DoRedirect"  />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" ItemStyle-CssClass="padding-left" HeaderText="Description" 
            SortExpression="description" >
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="padding-left" HorizontalAlign="Left" />

<ItemStyle CssClass="padding-left"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Last report" 
            SortExpression="name" >
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="120px" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="name" >
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MailReport
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected string renderthis(string sender)
        { 
            string str = sender.ToString()+"-str";
            return str;
        }
        protected void DoRedirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button theButton = sender as Button;
            Response.Redirect("Newpage.aspx?ID=" + theButton.CommandArgument);
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
    Compilation Error

    Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

    Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MailReport.WebForm1.renderthis(string)' has some invalid arguments

    Source Error:
    Line 25: <asp:Button runat="server" **

Text='<%#renderthis(Eval("id"))%>'** CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' OnClick="DoRedirect"  />
```

Please can you help me to understand this error and how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this function

from

```
protected string renderthis(string sender)
{ 
    string str = sender.ToString()+"-str";
    return str;
}
```

to

```
protected string renderthis(object sender)
{ 
    if(sender!=null)
    {
        string str = sender.ToString()+"-str";
        return str;
    }
    return "";
}
```